# Attempting to graph SQLite data in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import sqlite3
import time
import datetime
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib import style
style.use('fivethirtyeight')##Use any style you like

from dateutil import parser
from w1thermsensor import W1ThermSensor


conn = sqlite3.connect('temp_sensor2.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def graph_data():
        c.execute('SELECT datestamp, temperature FROM datetemp 
               ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10')
        data = c.fetchall()
        date = []
        temperature = []

        for row in data:
            date.append(parser.parse(row[0]))
            temperature.append(row[1])
        plt.plot_date(date,temperature,'-')##line style
        plt.show()

graph_data()
```

I am attempting to graph some temperature data in Python from a SQLite DB. The above code will generate a graph - however I am trying to graph the last 10 entries and it appears to be randomly picking 10 (consecutive) entries in the DB to graph. Any ideas? I know it is close!
Also the graph is not exactly corresponding with the timestamps but one thing at a time!!!
Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SQL statement:

```
'SELECT datestamp, temperature FROM datetemp ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10'
```

It's not clear how  how the id's are being generated. You might be sorting by some random 32 digit string.  If you want the 10 most recent entries try:

```
SELECT datestamp, temperature FROM datetemp ORDER BY datestamp DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Hi Ben, Many thanks for your response. That appears to have done the job - I had created the ID field with an increment for every iteration of the loop -> each loop took a reading and inserted it into the table.